# Fragments and slide over animation

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

After having spent quite a bit of time searching for this, I need to request help here.

I have a series of fragments each representing a "page".
I want to give the user a nice animation effect when going to the next page he has requested.

I want that the new fragment slides in over the previous fragment, hiding it as if it were a solid page.
At present I can slide in the new fragment, but we can still see the underlying fragment during the transition.

Here is my "slide in" transition definition :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="-1280"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

And here is my fade out transition

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

I apply it with :

```
Fragment f = (Fragment)FragClass.newInstance();
FragmentTransactionft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_in, R.animator.fragment_fade_out);
ft.replace(R.id.fl_frame, f);
ft.commit();
```

I have seen the kind of effect I want being demonstrated with the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#depth-page) - but I am using Fragments.
Can this kind of transition (just the moving in from the left bit shown at the end) be achieved with fragment animation ?
Or perhaps a mix of fragment animation and property animation ? - tried this but it got very messy.

I am building for Android 4.0 and above on tablets.

I do not want to use the ViewPager for this, trying to avoid the support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of experimentation and testing, here is the method I adopted.

Probably not the best, but it works for me.

1. Create an animator for fragments which does nothing
2. When creating the new fragment, pass in the initial X position, which is the negative width of the container view.  This will put the new fragment offset to the left of the container view and therefor hidden, for now.
3. Call setCustomAnimations on the FragmentTransaction with the "stay still" animation
4. Using the FragmentTransaction **add** the new fragment
5. Create an animation listener which, in onAnimationEnd, will call the containing view to do the following.
6. Swap the order of the two views by calling bringChildToFront
7. Start a new view animation on the old view to shrink it and fade it out
8. Start a new view animation on the new view to slide it in
9. Attach an AnimatorListener to the animation so that the old view can be removed at the animation end.

These are the steps to follow, the rest is just implementation :-D

Comment: How were you adding the AnimatorListener to the FragmentTransaction? I'm trying to solve this same problem and I'm not quite able to implement your solution.

Comment: @JessieA.Morris : the solution is not so direct.  The animation listener is not connected to the FragmentTransaction.  You will need to override the following function in each of your fragments : `public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)`.  Check to see if `nextAnim` is not 0 and then : `Animator anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), nextAnim);  anim.addListener( [your animator listener] );`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please share some code for solution, i want new fragment to slide above the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a significantly better solution than any of the others that have been proposed as of yet. What I did is the following:

```
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry entry = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(manager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
        Fragment oldFragment = manager.getFragments().get(entry.getId());

        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_left_out, R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_right_out);

        ft.hide(oldFragment);

        ft.add(R.id.container, login).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This makes is so that the fragment being removed is under the new fragment. It looks a little odd when the back button is pressed, but overall it's significantly better. :-)

Comment: What you propose here is interesting, but does not match the requirement I outlined above.  The underlying, outgoing fragment is supposed to "shrink" and fade out, not slide to the right, as you can see from the link I made to ViewPager.

Comment: So use different animations. Instead of R.anim.slide_left do R.anim.shrink_and_fade or whatever. The hard part was getting the new fragment above the old fragment, which my solution does.